# How can i get week no of year in sql server for year and month name

Tags: sql-server

i want to get week no of year from sql server . i have two input 1.Year name and 2 .month name .

like 
Year ---- '2016'
Month ---  'April'
Week no --- 1,2,3,4

Year  --- '2016'
Month ---'May'
Week no ----5,6,7,8

when user select year --- 2016 and month name --- April  then i want list of week no. like 1,2,3,4 of April month as financial year wise.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date as input(mm-dd-yyyy), this should help:

```
DECLARE @Dt datetime
SELECT @Dt='02-10-2016'
SELECT DATEPART( wk, @Dt)
```